# How to partition existing database?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a big database about 4.5Tb. Is it possible to partition it and move the half of it to another raid?

Thanks Arman.

PS.
I use Windows Server 2008 Standard  with Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up multiple secondary files with in enterprise manager, if you machine can see multiple logical disks you can provide storage space on a number of disks 
See

- [Understanding Files and Filegroups MS-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189563.aspx)
- [Using Files and Filegroups MS-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187087.aspx)

Once you have created filegroups you can assign tables to specific filegroups. File groups can be made up of files from different disks(or different RAID clusters). So you can spread your database and individual tables over multiple logical disk.

As this question is tagged with Sql-server I am assuming we are talking about Microsoft SQL Server.

Some more reading

- [Resources for Database Sharding and Partitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292039/resources-for-database-sharding-and-partitioning)
- [Sharding](http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2008/06/30/scale-cheaply-sharding/)
- [Partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146(SQL.90).aspx)
- [Data Dependent Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966448.aspx)

Comment: It turns out that the standard edition does not support partitioning

Comment: @Arman, just for the next person looking at this could you please be more specific. Are you meaning partitioning of tables, or having multiple secondary files, or having multiple secondary files on different drives?

Comment: @David, the standard edition does not support Table and Index Partitioning: for more details see: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx in the Scalability & Performance section.

Comment: @Arman so you can put different tables on different filegroups, just not split any given table up.

Comment: @David: Yes we did that last week, We got at least Indexes to build and backup was established. Before it was impossible.